# How to connect to local gremlin server using python

Tags: gremlin

I have a local gremlin server running:

```
bin/gremlin.sh
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/Users/jwan/Downloads/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.4/lib/groovy-2.5.7-indy.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
```

But I'm also trying to connect to it using python:

```
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from os import environ

graph = Graph()
>>> graph_db = traversal().withGraph(graph).withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection(f'ws://localhost:3000/gremlin','g'))
```

I get a connection refused error. How do I connect to this locally?

Answer (score 2):

That console session shows output from Gremlin Console not Gremlin Server. They are two totally different distributions. Download the Gremlin Server distribution [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/downloads.html) and start with `bin/gremlin-server.sh`. Your output should look like this after it has started:

```
[INFO] GremlinServer
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----

[INFO] GremlinServer - Configuring Gremlin Server from conf/gremlin-server-modern.yaml
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
[INFO] DefaultGraphManager - Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [conf/tinkergraph-empty.properties].
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines instances.
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine and registered metrics
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the standard OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the session OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
[INFO] TraversalOpProcessor - Initialized cache for TraversalOpProcessor with size 1000 and expiration time of 600000 ms
[INFO] GremlinServer - Executing start up LifeCycleHook
[INFO] Logger$info - Loading 'modern' graph data.
[INFO] GremlinServer - idleConnectionTimeout was set to 0 which resolves to 0 seconds when configuring this value - this feature will be disabled
[INFO] GremlinServer - keepAliveInterval was set to 0 which resolves to 0 seconds when configuring this value - this feature will be disabled
[WARN] AbstractChannelizer - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 serialization class is deprecated.
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0
[WARN] AbstractChannelizer - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 serialization class is deprecated.
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo-stringd with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.graphbinary-v1.0 with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.graphbinary-v1.0-stringd with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1
[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Gremlin Server configured with worker thread pool of 1, gremlin pool of 4 and boss thread pool of 1.
[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Channel started at port 8182.
```